# Visual Basic msgbox spam error

Tags: vb.net

In my program I have a progress bar that when it completes it displays a message, the problem is that when the message box is displayed it spams the msgboxes. here is my code

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        MsgBox("Done")
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    End If
```

If I could get an answer to make the messages stop spamming that would be great!

Comment: Which language is this? VB6? VBA? VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `msgbox` will stop the ui thread but not the timer thread, put the `timer1.stop()` before the `msgbox`

i just did a quick test and it is in fact true.